# Случайно удалил emmet в VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Случайно удалил emmet в VSCode, теперь не могу его восстановить, перепробовал разное, добавлял разные параметры в settings.json, но это ничего не дало, т.к. команды не отрабатывали из-за того, что emmet был удален полностью, несколько раз переустанавливал vscode, удалял все файлы, весь кэш программы с компьютера, почистил, APPDATA/Local, в общем вычистил все что можно, но при последующей переустановки vscoode подтягивал откуда-то стейты, и в итоге каждый раз он устанавливался без эммета. Еще также попробовал установить его заново, но в магазине расширений дефолтного эммета нет, после, я хотел его установить через VSIX с компьютера, но мне не удалось нигде в интернете найти установочный файл дефолтного эммета, создалось впечатление безвыходности ситуации, вроде бы простая проблема, но решить ее как-будто просто невозможно, кто с таким сталкивался прошу помочь советом, заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

В документации VSCode [написано](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) что Emmet не требует установки он встроен в VSCode, там же можно посмотреть настройки.

Что касается VSCode, то лично я его не устанавливал но у меня как описано в документации он имеется (я его не настраивал поэтому в настройках ничего нет):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На той же странице документации есть [ссылка](https://emmet.io/) где Emmet можно скачать, но похоже в отличии от `sublime` она ведет на скачивание VSCode - т.е. круг замкнулся.